# IDENTITY_INSERT error while trying to insert data into table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to copy data from a table named ActionType inside a database TD_EDD, into another table named ActionType inside another database DsVelocity.

I have written the following query:

```
INSERT INTO [DsVelocity].[dbo].[ActionType]
       ([ActionTypeID]
       ,[ActionTypeName]
       ,[ActiveStatus])
SELECT [ActionTypeID], [ActionType], [Active/Deactive]
FROM [TD_EDD].[dbo].[ActionType]
GO
```

Whenever I'm trying to do this, I'm getting the following error:

```
Msg 544, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'ActionType' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

I don't understand what's wrong and why I'm getting this error?

Note that I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that when you insert data into target table, you will have conflicting ids. Most likely ActionTypeId column

to Fix it use

```
INSERT INTO [DsVelocity].[dbo].[ActionType]
       ([ActionTypeName]
       ,[ActiveStatus])
SELECT [ActionType], [Active/Deactive]
FROM [TD_EDD].[dbo].[ActionType]
GO
```

Comment: I think this was the most concise and appropriate reply to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, lets assume from the message that ActionTypeID is an [IDENTITY Column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx). You cannot isert values into this column as it is auto generate, uless you use [IDENTITY_INSERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx)

> Allows explicit values to be inserted into the identity column of a
>   table.
>
> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT
>   property set to ON. If a table already has this property set to ON,
>   and a SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON statement is issued for another table,
>   SQL Server returns an error message that states SET IDENTITY_INSERT is
>   already ON and reports the table it is set ON for.
>
> If the value inserted is larger than the current identity value for
>   the table, SQL Server automatically uses the new inserted value as the
>   current identity value.
>
> The setting of SET IDENTITY_INSERT is set at execute or run time and
>   not at parse time.

So you would have to do something like

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DsVelocity].[dbo].[ActionType] ON
```

before the insert.

Comment: And then SET IDENTITY_INSERT [DsVelocity].[dbo].[ActionType] OFF after the insert.

Comment: Yes I did not have any idea about the IDENTITY_INSERT query and the basic functionality of it. Your reply helped me a lot to understand the concept. So many many thanks for your time and patience to answer my question.